# Where will my immigration held in USA if I had connecting flight in USA only?

Tags: customs-and-immigration

Hey guys I'm permanently shifting  (migrating) to US. I have flight from Mumbai to Charlotte via Dubai and New York. So can I immigrate at Charlotte ?or I have to New York. At New York I have 2hrs and 30 min hold.

Comment: Please post this question at expatriates stack exchange.

Comment: You need a more descriptive title. I don't want to edit your question in case that disrupts the close process, but pretty much everything on expats is an "immigration question." I suggest "where will my immigration process be handled when I have a connecting flight in the us?" or "is 2.5 hours enough for my immigration to be processed in New York?" Also please specify (in your new question on expats) which New York airport you are landing at.

Answer (score 2):

You will pass through immigration on arrival in New York.

Consider: The flight from New York to Charlotte will be full of Americans who are traveling internally in the USA and have not brought their passports. (Most Americans don't *have* a passport). There would be no way for the authorities to single you out for checking as you leave that plane, without checking *everyone*, which should not happen for a domestic flight.

So the universal rule is that you need to pass immigration inspection *before* you get to mingle with people who are already in the country. (In fact, the US follows the even simpler rule that *everyone* landing on an international flight will be checked, no matter where they're going afterwards).

Depending on which airport in New York and the time of day, 2.5 hours could be cutting it close -- but if your tickets are on a single booking, the airline will put you on a later plane to Charlotte if you're delayed by immigration lines.

Comment: We are three my mom and dad. The ticket  is one  way. So they will board us on next  flight  if we got delay due to immigration?.

Comment: And yeah We will land at jfk New York. The flight for Charlotte is at 17.35(terminal 5). We will land at terminal  4.